# Extract and manipulate data from FileMaker Pro 12 database with PyFileMaker2

Tags: python, filemaker

I'm trying to connect to a FileMaker Pro 12.0v4 database for extracting and manipulating data.
I have a Python 3.6.9 installed on a Windows10 64-bit PC.
The file name of the FileMaker database I try to connect to is "C:/prova.fmp12"

Reading the different materials I was able to find on the subject (eg, https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyfilemaker/, https://pypi.org/project/pyfilemaker2/), I imported successfully the PyFileMaker2 module

```
import pyfilemaker2
from pyfilemaker2.server import FmServer
from pyfilemaker2.metadata import FmMeta
from pyfilemaker2.errors import FmError
```

The next step should be to pass the following command:

```
fm = FmServer('login:password@filemaker.domain.com')
```

However, I do not understand what actually the 'login:password@filemaker.domain.com' string stands for.
I did multiple trials, but all the time when I then tried to get the name of the database:

```
fm.get_db_names()
```

I was given following messages:

> InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'login://None:80password@filemaker.domain.com?-dbnames='

So, it is not clear to me how to make the actual connection to the file ('c:/prova.fmp12') and how to extract the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyFileMaker connects to a FileMaker Server instance and your FileMaker File needs to be hosted on FileMaker Server with XML sharing enabled. Since you say that your FileMaker File is at C:/prova.fmp12 I imagine that you do not have prova.fmp12 hosted on a FileMaker Server.

> login:password@filemaker.domain.com

This breaks down to

- login = FileMaker File Username for an account with XML access priviliges
- password = FileMaker File Password
- filemaker.domain.com = The DNS that points to your FileMaker Server.

From the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/pyfilemaker2/

> You will also need a FileMaker server with the XML enabled of course.